# Adding a new line to a form that consists of Select Boxes

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form that is asking users to enter rooms of a house. I would like them to be able to add as many "rooms" as they would like. Each room on the form consists of two Selection Boxes and two text fields. 
I have a js function that is adding a new selection box by using .innerHTML however if I dont put all the code on a single line it will not work. One of the selection boxes has quite a few options and I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this?

The function is called by a button click, below is how I would like to do it but it will only work if I put all Options on a single line within a single .innerHTML    Thanks!

```
function add_room() {

    var room_count = 0;
    write = document.getElementById('new_room')

    write.innerHTML +='<select name="level[]" id="levels"' + room_count + '/> ';
    write.innerHTML +='<option>Basement</option>';
    write.innerHTML +='<option>Lower Level</option>';
    write.innerHTML +='<option>Main Floor</option>';
    write.innerHTML +='<option>2nd Floor</option>';
    write.innerHTML +='<option>3rd Floor</option></select>';

    room_count++;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append all the options as a string into a variable and then assign it to innerHTML.

```
function add_room() {

    var room_count = 0;
    write = document.getElementById('new_room')
    var roomSelect = '<select name="level[]" id="levels"' + room_count + '/> ';
    roomSelect += '<option>Basement</option>';
    roomSelect += '<option>Lower Level</option>';
    roomSelect += '<option>Main Floor</option>';
    roomSelect += '<option>2nd Floor</option>';
    roomSelect += '<option>3rd Floor</option></select>';
    write.innerHTML += roomSelect;
    room_count++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It seems that when the select and the options are placed in a variable as a string the function will only run once instead of creating a new line every time the button is clicked. It does work perfectly on the first click though???

Comment: That is because you are rewriting the innerHTML of the *new_room* element. Instead append it to the element.  replace `write.innerHTML = roomSelect;` with *write.innerHTML += roomSelect;*

Comment: Thank you sooo much!! Works great... Just on a side note is there a better way to do this kind of thing or am I somewhat on the right track?  Thanks again.

Comment: Sorryyy just came across an issue where all but the first selection boxes reset when you add a new row. So I would have to add all the rows I want before using any of the selection boxes. Do you see any way around this?? Also is there away to delete a row that was accidentally added Sorry to be a bother... Cheers